# Replace foreach with lambda while updating list

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, lambda

I want to update vmlist by geting values from vlist without using any foreach loop.

For now I am just doing this with `foreach` loop, but I want to replace this `foreach` with LINQ

```
foreach (var item in vlist){
    vmlist.Where(list => list.SId==item.SId && list.ParameterId==item.ParameterId && list.WId==item.WId)
    .Select(li => { li.Value = item.Value; return li; }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: *Why* don't you want to use a `foreach` loop? Personally I'd definitely use a nested `foreach` loop here rather than your current abuse of LINQ to include side-effects and force evaluation with `ToList`.

Comment: Note that when you say "lambda" you really mean "LINQ"... lambda expressions are just an element of syntax in C#. An alternative to a nested foreach would be a join, by the way.

Comment: i think it's time consuming in execution using foreach

Comment: Then you haven't understood what your current code does, or how LINQ works.

Comment: i knw there is already nested iteration, but i just want to avoid foreach

Comment: Hint: what do you think `ToList()` does under the hood? It uses `foreach` or an equivalent. What aspect of `foreach` do you think is "time consuming"? Something *has* to iterate over the items you want to change - but at least you can optimize that with a join, as shown in my answer.

Comment: i hav removed that ToList(), is there any way to do it in single query?

Comment: Without `ToList()`, your code won't do anything - you're creating a query and then not evaluating the results. You know how you evaluate results? By iterating over the query. Like with a `foreach` loop. But *please* stop abusing LINQ by including side-effects in queries. Try the code in my answer - it should be more efficient than your current code, *and* it's clearer IMO.

Comment: thanks, i will go ahead with my current foreach code which is working fine

Comment: No, please *don't* do that. Your current code is non-idiomatic and inefficient in two different ways. Why would you want to use that code rather than the join code in my answer? It's worth making sure you understand *why* your code is bad, in terms of putting a side-effect into a LINQ query, as well as the use of `ToList()` to force execution. If you don't want to do a join, at least use a nested `foreach` loop instead...

Answer (score 4):

Your current approach is very inefficient - it's O(N * M) *and* it creates a list on each iteration.

Using a join would be more efficient - I would still use a `foreach` loop, but separate the querying part from the update part:

```
var pairsToUpdate = from original in vmlist
                    join item in vlist
                      on new { original.SId, original.ParameterId, original.WId }
                      equals new { item.SId, item.ParameterId, item.WId }
                    select new { original, item };

foreach (var pair in pairsToUpdate)
{
    pair.original.Value = pair.item.Value;
}
```

- No abuse of `Select` with side-effects
- No extra lists created for no good reason
- More efficient selection of items to update